Events $A$, $B$, $C$ satisfy: $0 < P(C) < 1$, $P(A|C) > P(A|C′)$ and $P(B|C) > P(B|C′)$. Is it true that: $P(A \cap B|C) > P(A \cap B|C′)$?
Events $A$, $B$, $C$ satisfy the conditions: $0 < \mathbb{P}(C) < 1$, $\mathbb{P}(A|C) > \mathbb{P}(A|C′)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B|C) > \mathbb{P}(B|C′)$.
Does it follow that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B|C) > \mathbb{P}(A \cap B|C′)$?
I think it can be argued that:

$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} > \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')}$

$\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} > \frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')}$


The inequality to be verified is equal to:
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} > \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')}$$
Now, we can sum the first inequalities and get:
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} + \frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} > \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')} + \frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')}$$
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C) + \mathbb{P}(B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} > \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C') + \mathbb{P}(B \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')}$$
It is true that:
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C) + \mathbb{P}(B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} >\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}$$
And that:
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C') + \mathbb{P}(B \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')} > \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C')}{\mathbb{P}(C')}$$
I thought that I would be able to use those inequalities to get some prove of the inequality that is to be verified, but now I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Suppose you are tossing a fair six sided die.  Define:  $$C=\{1,2,3\}\quad A=\{1,2,4\}\quad B=\{2,3,4\}$$
Then of course:
$$P(A\,|\,C)=\frac 23> \frac 13=P(A\,|\,C^c)$$
$$P(B\,|\,C)=\frac 23>\frac 13=P(B\,|\,C^c)$$
So the assumptions are met.
But $A\cap B=\{2,4\}$ So whether we have $C$ or $C^c$, the conditional probability of $A\cap B$ is $\frac 13$.
More extreme examples are possible.  Suppose that you were tossing a fair ten sided die and that $$C_1=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\quad A_1=\{1,2,6\}\quad B_1=\{4,5,6\}$$ for instance.
